My VBA code to send emails with attachments stops sending at random points in the list
I'm using the below code to send emails w/ attachments.  It works fine for a while.  Then, the process just stops with this error code - RunTime error 440:  The object does not support this method.  It always stops on the SentOnBehalfOf line.
My current dataset is 163 emails with single file attachment of ~100kb.  Any ideas why it stops?  It does not stop in the same place each time or on the same email address or file.
Dim OutLookApp As Object
Dim OutLookMailItem As Object
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim MailDest As String
Dim subj As String
Dim att As Variant

Sheets("Email Tab").Activate

lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Email Tab").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'change worksheet as needed

For i = 2 To lastRow

    Set OutLookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
    Set OutLookMailItem = OutLookApp.CreateItem(0)
    Set Attach = OutLookMailItem.Attachments

    With OutLookMailItem
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = [E6]
        .To = Cells(i, 1).Value
        .CC = [E4]
        .Subject = [E5] & " " & " Details"
        .Body = "Dear Pet Partner," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Attached are your items for the upcoming " & MyTheme & " offer. Please review the document to ensure funding matches what was agreed upon with your merchant.  You have 5 business days to review and let us know if any corrections are needed.  No response will be interpreted as confirmation to proceed with the offer as shown." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Thank you," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "PSP Group Merchandising" & vbNewLine & "Pet Supplies Plus" & vbNewLine & "17410 College Parkway, Livonia, MI 48152"
        On Error Resume Next
            For Each att In Split(Cells(i, 2).Value, ",")
            Attach.Add [E2] & att & ".xlsx" 'change cell reference in brackets as needed
        Next
        .Display
        On Error GoTo 0
        .Send
    End With

Next

I tried putting a pause of 2 seconds in between each email sent, but that actually caused it to quit much sooner.  I've run it 4 times today and gotten 87, 142, 63 & 99 of the 163 emails to send.  I can't understand why it won't send them all.
I've updated the loop based on @Niton's feedback, but the result is unchanged.  Still only a portion of the emails send.  I'm also checking with my internal IT team to see if there is some kind of restriction/limitation within our environment that could be causing this.
For i = 2 To lastRow
Set OutLookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
Set OutLookMailItem = OutLookApp.CreateItem(0)
Set Attach = OutLookMailItem.Attachments

With OutLookMailItem
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = [E6]
    .To = Cells(i, 1).Value
    .CC = [E4]
    .Subject = [E5] & " " & " Details"
    .Body = "Dear Pet Partner," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Attached are your items for the upcoming " & MyTheme & " offer. Please review the document to ensure funding matches what was agreed upon with your merchant.  You have 5 business days to review and let us know if any corrections are needed.  No response will be interpreted as confirmation to proceed with the offer as shown." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Thank you," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "PSP Group Merchandising" & vbNewLine & "Pet Supplies Plus" & vbNewLine & "17410 College Parkway, Livonia, MI 48152"
    On Error Resume Next
        For Each att In Split(Cells(i, 2).Value, ",")
        Attach.Add [E2] & att & ".xlsx" 'change cell reference in brackets as needed
    Next
    .Display
    On Error GoTo 0
    .Send
End With

Set OutLookMailItem = Nothing
Set Attach = Nothing
Set OutLookApp = Nothing

Next

Move Set OutLookApp = CreateObject(".application") out of the loop then retest.

probably remove some sensitive information if it is not already removed :)

Niton's suggestion did not solve the issue.  It sent 82 emails after making that change and errored at the same spot.

Set OutLookMailItem = Nothing and Set Attach = Nothing before Next followed by Set OutLookApp = Nothing. Consider editing the question to indicate updated code. Restart to ensure leftover pieces of OutLookApp, if any, are cleaned up.

If moving CreateObject above For i = and Set OutLookApp = Nothing below Next has no impact, the logic is at least more efficient.
